# Use of the composite pattern

Tags: c#, object-oriented, design-patterns

Assume the following requirements:

[image]

Is it a good idea to use the Composite design-pattern for this, taking into account that there will be:

- Only 1 `TestPlan`
- a `TestPlan` can only have `TestSequence`s
- a `TestSequence` can only have `Test`s
- a `Test` can only have `Assert`s

I've started coding using the *Composite pattern* but I got the feeling that this pattern cannot enforce the above rules.
Is my feeling correct and should I use another design (pattern) here?
Or is using the composite pattern here correct but is my implementation of it just wrong?

```
public abstract class TestElement
{
    public TestElement(int id)
    {
        this.Id = id;
    }

    public virtual void Add(TestElement element)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public virtual void Remove(TestElement element)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public virtual IEnumerable<TestElement> GetElements()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public virtual TestElement GetElement(int index)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public string Id { get; private set; }

    public abstract void Setup();

    public abstract void Teardown();

}


    public class TestPlan : TestElement
{
    // Here TestElement should only be of type TestSequence
    private IList<TestElement> Children = new List<TestElement>();

    public TestPlan(int id)
        : base(id)
    {
    }

    public override void Add(TestElement element)
    {
        this.Children.Add(element);
    }

    public override void Remove(TestElement element)
    {
        this.Children.Remove(element);
    }

    public override TestElement GetElement(int index)
    {
        return this.Children.ElementAt(index);
    }

    public override IEnumerable<TestElement> GetElements()
    {
        return this.Children;
    }

    public override void Setup()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Setup executed for TestPlan " + Id);
    }

    public override void Teardown()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Teardown executed for TestPlan " + Id);
    }
}


    public class TestSequence : TestElement
{
    // Here TestElement should only be of type Test
    private IList<TestElement> Children = new List<TestElement>();

    public TestSequence(int id)
        : base(id)
    {
    }

    public override void Add(TestElement element)
    {
        this.Children.Add(element);
    }

    public override void Remove(TestElement element)
    {
        this.Children.Remove(element);
    }

    public override TestElement GetElement(int index)
    {
        return this.Children.ElementAt(index);
    }

    public override IEnumerable<TestElement> GetElements()
    {
        return this.Children;
    }

    public override void Setup()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Setup executed for TestSequence " + Id);
    }

    public override void Teardown()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Teardown executed for TestSequence " + Id);
    }
}

public class Test : TestElement
{
    // Here TestElement should only be of type Assert
    private IList<TestElement> Children = new List<TestElement>();

    public Test(int id)
        : base(id)
    {
    }

    public override void Add(TestElement element)
    {
        this.Children.Add(element);
    }

    public override void Remove(TestElement element)
    {
        this.Children.Remove(element);
    }

    public override TestElement GetElement(int index)
    {
        return this.Children.ElementAt(index);
    }

    public override IEnumerable<TestElement> GetElements()
    {
        return this.Children;
    }

    public override void Setup()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Setup executed for Test " + Id);
    }

    public override void Teardown()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Teardown executed for Test " + Id);
    }
}



public class Assert : TestElement
{
    public Assert(int id)
        : base(id)
    {
    }

    public override void Setup()
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException("No setup with Assert.");
    }

    public override void Teardown()
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException("No teradown with Assert.");
    }

    public bool ExecuteAssert()
    {
        return true;
    }
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think this is an example of composite pattern. Composite is defined as

> The Composite Pattern allows you to compose objects into tree
>   structures to represent part-whole hierarchies. Composite lets clients
>   treat individual objects and compositions of objects uniformly.

Main idea of Composite is to allow treating whole (several parts) as a individual part. I.e. when client asks Composite to do something, then it means that Composite will ask all it's Components to do same thing. But neither `Setup` nor `Teardown` methods of your Composite do not touch collection of `TestElements`. So, you simply have set of classes with some base class, but that is not Composite.

If you would like to treat `TestSequence` or `TestPlan` as a single `Test` then it would be a Composite. I.e. if you would add `Run` functionality to your base class (or interface)

```
public interface ITest
{
    void Run();
}
```

and `TestSequence` would run all it's tests:

```
public class TestSequence : ITest
{
    private IList<ITest> tests = new List<ITest>();

    public void Run()
    {
        Setup();
        foreach(var test in tests)
           test.Run();
        Teardown();
    }

    public void Setup()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Setup executed for Test " + Id);
    }

    public void Teardown()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Teardown executed for Test " + Id);
    }
}
```

Then `TestSequence` would be a `Composite`, because it's completely transparent for client whether it works with single part (`Test`) or with a whole (`TestSequence`, collection of `Tests`). Same with `TestPlan` - you can treat it as a single `TestSequence`. Thus you can treat `TestSequence` as single `Test`, then for client `TestPlan` can also be treated as single `Test`. Client can run `TestPlan`, and it will run all it's test sequences, which in their turn will run all tests.

Comment: This makes sence. One more question though: is there a way to enforce that `TestPlan`can only contain `TestSequence`as child (and so on)? Or is that something I can take care of in my Builder.

Comment: @Koen yes, you can. All client should know about `TestPlan` or `TestSequence` is that it is runnable. You can create base class `CompositeTest` which will provide collection for storing child tests and method `Run()` which runs all children (as above). In that case restriction of children types goes to builder and interface of composite (e.g. `TestPlan` can have only method `Add (TestSequence sequence)`. If you don't need base composite class, then each composite can hold collection of specific children (i.e. `TestSequece` list for `TestPlan`)

Comment: Ok. Thx for the info.